# How to sort by custom field (price)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Can someone please help me with this, I have spent over 8 hours researching and trying to figure it out on my own.  So I figured I would make a account here and try my luck...

I am making a website for realtors to add their listings. So I created a custom post type for Listings. In this custom post type I added custom inputs with the following code (This is just a snippet so you can see how I defined each custom field):

```
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_listing_meta',TRUE); 
?>
<p><label>City:</label><input name="listing_meta[city]" value="<?php echo $meta['city']; ?>" /></p>
<p><label>Area/Region:</label><input name="listing_meta[region]" value="<?php echo $meta['region']; ?>" /></p>
<p><label>Price:</label><input name="listing_meta[price]" value="<?php echo $meta['price']; ?>" /></p>
<p><label>MLS#:</label><input name="listing_meta[mls]" value="<?php echo $meta['mls']; ?>" /></p>
<?php
```

Next, in my content.php file I display the price like this:

```
<?php
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_listing_meta',TRUE);
echo '<div class="listing-price">$'.$meta['price'].'</div>';
?>
```

This works perfectly as far as the custom fields go.  But I can not for the life of me get it to sort the listings in price order...

Please let me know if this is enough info to help me.  If you need anything more I will be happy to provide it.

Here is my loop (it is just the standard TwentyFifteen loop):

```
<?php
// Start the Loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
// End the loop.
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Can you share your loop / how you're querying for these posts?

Comment: I added the loop I am using to my question :)

Answer (score -1):

Can you show your wp query which you are using to fetch the listings? Your query should look something like below

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'listings',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'listing_meta',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
));
```

Comment: Hmm I haven't done anything like that yet... The posts are being displayed how the TwentyFifteen theme displays them. I just made a duplicate of the theme and have been editing it as I go. Do I need to add something like that to the loop?

Comment: After Adding that code above my loop, all of the posts became blank.  They were still there, but no info / pictures...

Comment: That is a query you will need to change your loop accordingly